# Angular 5 app with server rendering with Angular Universal on App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, angular-universal

I am newbie to node.js & angular and I have simple Angular app build Angular 5 with some simple routes.

I also want to support server side rendering in my app with Angular Universal and host my app on Google Cloud App Engine.

I tried to upload a starter kit of angular universal on App Engine it fails. (https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter).I have deployed it using docker. Although deploy is successful but it gives 502 Bad Gateway error for nginx. I have tried clearing cache and all other suggestion avaliable on net. But still same result.

I have also tried example from Google: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex worked but it is basic.

Please help me create a App Engine deploy-able version of code https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter.

Comment: Bad gateway might mean that the node js server crash. Try accessing the url on the node js port directly instead of going through nginx, and check server side error logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I go into any detail, let me give you the Github link of my Angular Universal seed project with `Dockerfile` and Sass. I use it as a starting point for my projects. Since I am a fan of Vagrant, you will find the `Vagranfile` in the repository and use it to create the exact same environment for development as well as testing the Docker container. The Readme file provides all the details as to how to work with the project.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/saptarshibasu/angular-universal-setup).

**Angular Universal Project Creation**

The Angular Universal setup steps are detailed [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal) in the official documentation.

However, I had a few wasted hours to find out the following point

- Webpack 3 is not compatible with ts-loader versions higher than
  3.5.0. At the time of developing this, the latest version of Angular CLI is 1.7.2 which uses Webpack 3.*. Hence, while setting up Angular
  Universal, install `ts-config@3.5.0`

**Dockerfile**

My `Dockerfile` looks like below. So, as you can see, I am using the docker feature multi stage build to first build the project in a container, copying the distribution to a new container and discarding the old container used for build. This allows Google Cloud build trigger to build the source code and create the Docker image from the distribution.

```
FROM node:8.10.0 AS ausbuilder
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash aus; \
    chown -R aus /home/aus
USER aus
WORKDIR /home/aus
COPY aus/ /home/aus
RUN mkdir /home/aus/.npm; \
    npm config set prefix /home/aus/.npm; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress -g webpack@3.11.0; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@1.7.2; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress;
ENV PATH=/home/aus/.npm/bin:$PATH
RUN npm run build; \
    webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --no-progress

FROM keymetrics/pm2:8-alpine
RUN adduser -h /home/aus -s /bin/bash aus; \
    chown -R aus /home/aus
USER aus
WORKDIR /home/aus
COPY --from=ausbuilder /home/aus/dist /home/aus/dist
EXPOSE 4000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2-runtime","start","/home/aus/dist/server.js"]
```

**Deployment in Kubernetes in Google Cloud**

We need to first create a build trigger in Google Cloud, so that as soon as we push the code in (let's say) the master branch, the code build and subsequent deployment is triggered. Your code may be hosted in Google Cloud source control, Bitbucket or Github. You need to integrate your source control with the build trigger.While creating the build trigger, you will have option to select either `Dockerfile` or `cloudbuild.yaml`, if you chose the first option, your code will be built and subsequently the Docker image will be stored in the Google Container Repository. I go for the second option as it allows me to do more like deployment in Kubernetes.

Here is how my cloudbuild.yaml looks like.

A few important points to note here:

1. While cloning the repository I cannot give any external URL. So, what happens here is when you create a build trigger, google creates another repository in the Google domain which basically points to the external source control like Bitbucket in my case. You can find this in the Google Source Control section.
2. Secondly, I am creating a tag `latest` for the container image so that I can refer it in the Kubernetes deployment descriptor which I named as `kubedeployment.yaml`. `kubedeployment.yaml` is referenced in the `cloudbuild.yaml` as you can see below

---

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args: ['clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/aus2018/r/bitbucket-saptarshibasu-aus']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/aus2018/aus:$REVISION_ID", "."]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["tag", "gcr.io/aus2018/aus:$REVISION_ID", "gcr.io/aus2018/aus:latest"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/aus2018/aus:$REVISION_ID"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/aus2018/aus:latest"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args:
  - 'create'
  - '-f'
  - 'kubedeployment.yaml'
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=asia-south1-a'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=aus'
```

Finally, here is how the `kubedeployment.yaml` looks:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aus-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: aus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: aus
          image: gcr.io/aus2018/aus:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aus-svc
  labels: 
    app: aus
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: aus
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aus-ing
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: aus-svc
    servicePort: 80
```

Once deployment is complete after a few minutes, you'll get the Ingress URL. And then after a few minutes you app starts showing up at the URL.

You are definitely going to customise this to fit your needs. However, I hope, this would probably give you a starting point.